# import torch error in google Colaboratory

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I get the following error on google colaboratory.

> ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 import torch
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/**init**.py in ()
>        54 except ImportError:
>        55     pass
>   ---> 56 from torch._C import *
>        57 
>        58 **all** += [name for name in dir(_C)
>
> ImportError: No module named _C

I tried importing from a different directory. But, still get the same error. Any help?

Comment: Hey! Did you fix your issues?

Answer (score 5):

Try restarting runtime. Colab sometimes gives errors like this :P

Answer (score 0):

Generally that suggests you are in a dir called `torch`. See [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7).

Answer (score 0):

check if you imported torch via :
import torch